# How to change button text onclick with toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

Button:

```
<button type="submit" id="status" class="button" value="True"><span>followed</span></button>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(".button").toggle(function() {
    $(this).val('followed');
}, function(){
    $(this).val('follow');
});
</script>
```

When the user clicks the button I want it to toggle to the other value. But right now when I run the code the button just disappears from the page! What's wrong with this code?

Edit:
Thanks for the help. 
Here is the entire updated jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function() {
        var status = $("#status").val();
        var course = $("#course").html()

        //NEW SECTION that I'm having trouble with
        if ($(".button span").html() == "followed") {
            $(".button").on("mouseover", function () {
            $(".button span").html() = "unfollow";
}}

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/follow",
            data: 'status=' + status + "&course=" + course,
            success: function() {
$(".button span").html($(".button span").html() == 'followed' ? 'follow' : 'followed');
$(".button").val($(".button").val() == 'True' ? 'False' : 'True');
}
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The onclick works. I then added the new onmouseover code to change "followed" to "unfollowed", and when I run it I get

```
405 Method Not Allowed

The method POST is not allowed for this resource.
```

What's wrong with the onmouseover code?

Also, what is the function of

```
return false;
```

?

Comment: You need to set up the click event.

Comment: @darkmango: depending on what version of jquery you are using. Please see my demo below. You must be using the newer version. For this to work you have to use 1.8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rPuQ9/)

```
$(".button").click(function() {
     $(".button span").html($(".button span").html() == 'followed' ? 'follow' : 'followed');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're probably new to jQuery here's a lil translation of what the others posted since you / someone might not know `?` `:` operators yet.:

```
$i = 1;

$(function () {
    $(".button").click(function () {
        if ($i === 0) {
            $(this).text("followed");
            $i = 1;
        } else {
            $(this).text("follow");
            $i = 0;
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks. could you see what is wrong with the new mouseover code? (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery toggle shows or hides elements.  You are not using it correctly.  You should use `.on('click', function()`, or `.click(function()` instead.

Also, for the text, you should use `.text()`, or `.html()` to include span tags, which you seem to have in your button.

See docs: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

### Update with example code

```
// native element tags perform better than classname selectors
// so use button instead of .button
$('button').click(function () { 
    var text = 'follow';
    // save $(this) so jQuery doesn't have to execute again
    var $this = $(this).find('span');
    if ($this.text() === text) {
        $this.text('followed');
    } else {
        $this.text(text)
    }
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/fNL43/).

Comment: Isn't there another usage of [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)?  "Bind two or more handlers to the matched elements, to be executed on alternate clicks." Edit: never mind, it's been "deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9".

Answer (score 1):

Toggle is meant to "Display or hide the matched elements."

You just need to listen for the click event:

```
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html() == 'follow' ? 'followed' : 'follow');
});
```

Comment: Does .val work?  Or does it have to be .text or .html?

Comment: You are right, copy pasted his code without looking at that part too much

Answer (score 0):

The toggle click has been deprecated in the newer jQuery api. But the older still works. The reason why it gets removed on your end is because you are using the newer version, which is equivalent of fade toggle. Look at my demo using Jquery 1.8

```
<input type="button" onclick ="play" value="play"/>

 $("input[type='button']").toggle(function (){
       $(this).val("Pause");
    }, function(){
    $(this).val("Play");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oVoGixi/2/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you can get solution:

just create function  `sign_in_up(idElement)`

**JS:**

```
  function sign_in_up(idElement) {
        var element = document.getElementById('element' + idElement);
        if (idElement === 1 || idElement === 2) {
            if (element.innerHTML === 'SIGN IN') element.innerHTML = 'SIGN UP';
            else {
                element.innerHTML = 'SIGN IN';
            }
        }
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <button onClick="javascript:sign_in_up(1)" ></button>    
 <div id="element1"> SIGN UP </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).text()==='Click me away!' ? $(this).text('i am clic') : $(this).text('Click me away!');
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<button type="submit">Click me away!</button>
<button type="submit">Click me also</button>

</body>
</html>
```